# What Kind of Connotations are Associated with the word 'Bruv'?

Tags: british-english, slang, connotation, australian-english

I encountered the slang word '[bruv](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bruv)' for the first time not long ago while playing [*Borderlands: The Pre-Sequel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borderlands:_The_Pre-Sequel!).

The word is used quite a lot by a genius scientist character named [Gladstone Katoa](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Gladstone_Katoa), but I think other characters use it as well. The game was made by 2K Australia, and a lot of the voice actors have Australian accents. It also seems like they're probably using Australian slang, but never having been to Australia I can't say for sure. Some of the characters seem more English than Australian, but they're all in an absurd sci-fi setting on a fictional planet, so they aren't really of any Earth nationality.

To my American ears, this word sounds a lot like '[bro](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bro)'. 'Bro' has a *lot* of connotations in American English, summarized a bit in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bro_%28subculture%29). Basically, if you use the word 'bro' a lot, many will think you an uneducated fool.

It may be useful to note that Gladstone does not have a thick accent, and he's not pronouncing every 'th' as a 'v', he's just using this word a lot when speaking directly to the player, whom he barely knows.

Hearing a genius scientist say 'bro' over and over would be a bit odd, and therefore hearing Gladstone say 'bruv' over and over sounds odd to me. I'm wondering if this was intentional on the part of the game designers.

In other words, should Gladstone saying 'bruv' all the time sound incongruous, or would a native British or Australian English speaker feel that it sounded completely natural?

Comment: Would you have the same questions about "scientists" using the short form ***sis**?* Note that ***bruv*** is primarily BrE, and ***bro*** is primarily (or at least, *originally*) AmE (specifically, [AAVE](http://www.hawaii.edu/satocenter/langnet/definitions/aave.html)), but ***sis*** is the same everywhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers To someone unfamiliar with *th*-fronting, this is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'Sis' doesn't have even remotely the same connotations as 'bro', so I'm not sure how relevant this is, but I would find a scientist (or anyone else, really) constantly referring to someone they barely know as 'sis' quite odd as well.

Comment: @DCShannon - I can't say what connotations "bro" and "sis" carry for you, today - I don't hear them as much anymore - but these terms are affectionate diminutives, just as FumbleFingers related. They also signaled solidarity in our war against the senex of the day. Back then, we sisters were losing brothers every day to a bloody war in Vietnam, so the solidarity and affection were real and the words heart-felt. "Bro" & "Sis" had wide currency on America's college campuses and those of us who used the terms were never considered fools, educated or otherwise.

Comment: +1 @DCShannon - Back then we were brother and sisters even when we were total strangers, with a shared intimacy stemming perhaps from a precocious sense of our own mortality. I certainly don't miss the war, but I certainly do miss the brotherhood, the sisterhood.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'bro' is hardly specific to AAVE. I'm not sure it is even used in AAVE, at least not currently.

Comment: @Mitch: What do I know? I'm BrE, and I usually call my brothers ***bruv***. But [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bro) specifically says it is, and definition #4 at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bro) says *a **fellow black male**; soul brother.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's exactly why I don't trust dictionaries, especially freely ones.

Comment: @Mitch: You have me at a loss. Are you saying dictionaries are useless, and that I should only believe what ***you*** say? Why in that case would ELU specifically encourage us to back up whatever we say here with *references?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm not saying they're useless. They're better as a reference for someone who knows already (where they can judge appropriately), rather than as a learning tool. Also, use multiple sources to get a better view on words you don't know already.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "bro" *was* specifically African-American English initially because this diminution of "brother" originated in A-A communities prior to its adoption by counter-cultural Americans of every stripe.

Answer (score 6):

*Bruv* can be a friendly, jocular way to greet a close friend or indeed a brother.

In London, I wouldn't hear it being used among strangers unlike the female expression *luv* which means *love* or its male version *mate*.

A London black cab driver might ask a female passenger:

> "Where are you going, *luv*?"

But to a male customer he is more likely to say:

> "Where to *guv'nor*?" (an old fashioned term for *governor*, if he looked "important") or just *mate*.

But among friends who are of a similar age one might hear this greeting:

> What's happen' bruv?
>   What's up bruv?

As to whether the listener or receiver would consider the speaker to be uneducated or uncouth, I would say "absolutely not!" It's a very friendly dialectal term used mainly among Londoners. Unfortunately I can't say if the term is used in other inner cities in the UK, it could be.

As I already mentioned, a BrEng speaker (of either sex) is unlikely to greet a stranger as *bruv* or *bruvver*, but if they did it would be simply brushed off. Obviously in a more formal context such as a job interview, it would be a serious faux pas and would reflect negatively on their character and level of manners.

Comment: Okay, that makes it sound more like 'man' or 'buddy' than 'bro'. Do you have any comments on the Urban Dictionary entry I linked which characterizes 'bruv' as a 'chav' word? I'm not really that familiar with the concept of chavs, but it looks pretty derogative.

Comment: It has more of a Cockney feel to it, rather than someone who is a Chav, but I wouldn't exclude it from their vocabulary. I would say the term *bruvver* has an older history than chavs, so it's not exclusively associated with that social group.

Comment: [1906 excerpt](https://books.google.it/books?id=hGU3AQAAMAAJ&q=%22my+bruvver%22&dq=%22my+bruvver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hz_yVMX1JOXXyQPV74C4DA&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBg) *It 's to pay for Billy-what he stole,” stammered the boy. “ Who is Billy? And what did he steal? ” “ Billy 's my bruvver. He stole a strap 'longside your hitching'post; I don't b'lieve he knew it b'longed to you. We lives in the house back of your stable.*

Comment: [Dialect Play-readings (1940)](https://books.google.it/books?id=5efyAAAAMAAJ&q=%22my+bruvver%22&dq=%22my+bruvver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1kDyVL2XDMnmywPy0YCABg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBjgK) *P'r'aps you're my bruvver — anyway you're my best pal*

Answer (score 4):

> [Bruv](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bruv) is a word used by mainly South Londoners. It's the shorter version of 'bruvva' which is a slang variation of 'brother'. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bruv)

> [Bruv](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bruv) is shortened from bruvver: (UK, slang) brother, mate, friend. [Wiktionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bruv)

Comment: I'm UK SE, and completely agree with this.

Comment: And I was born in North London and lived there until I was a teenager. The definition is correct.